# Problems with the object ( dictionary ) I get from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift2

Although the app works well I still get this warning message on two of my code lines. What I am trying to do is to get the previous scores from two players:

**The Global Variables:**

// Player 1 has an initial score of 0 , the player 2 as well.

```
var countWins:Dictionary = ["1":0,"2":0]
```

**The Warning:**

> Treating a forced downcast to 'Int' as optional will never produce
>   'nil'

on the lines ->

```
countWins["1"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") as! Int
countWins["2"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") as! Int
```

**The Whole Function:**

```
func loadScores()
{

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") != nil && 

    defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") != nil 

{
    countWins["1"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") as! Int
    countWins["2"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") as! Int


        scorePlayerOne.text = String(countWins["1"]!)
        scorePlayerTwo.text = String(countWins["2"]!)

    }
}
```

I do not know if it matters but I call the function from func viewDidLoad() , as it is logic I try to load the previous scores when the app is back.

It must be a error of concept. Optional Objects are getting me in trouble all the time. ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat it as a `conditional` downcast to `Int` *instead* of `optional`:

```
countWins["1"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") as? Int
countWins["2"] = defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") as? Int
```

Otherwise if you need optional then add parentheses around it to silence the warning:

```
countWins["1"] = (defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") as! Int)
countWins["2"] = (defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") as! Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use optionals in user defaults if the keys don't change

In `AppDelegate` register the keys with default values, put the code in `awakeFromNib()` or better in `init()`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["scoreOne" : 0, "scoreTwo" : 0];
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

If none of the keys has been written to disk yet, user defaults takes the default values otherwise the actual values.

Now you can load the values as non optionals

```
func loadScores()
{
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let scoreOne = defaults.integerForKey("scoreOne")
  let scoreTwo = defaults.integerForKey("scoreTwo")
  countWins["1"] = scoreOne
  countWins["2"] = scoreTwo

  scorePlayerOne.text = String(scoreOne)
  scorePlayerTwo.text = String(scoreTwo)
}
```

No optional bindings - no type casting.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using optional binding. It will get rid of your warnings, and increase the safety of your application.

```
var countWins:Dictionary = ["1":0,"2":0]

func loadScores() {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let scoreOne = defaults.objectForKey("scoreOne") as? Int,
       let scoreTwo = defaults.objectForKey("scoreTwo") as? Int {

        countWins["1"] = scoreOne
        countWins["2"] = scoreTwo

        scorePlayerOne.text = "\(scoreOne)"
        scorePlayerTwo.text = "\(scoreTwo)"
    }
    else {
        scorePlayerOne.text = "\(0)"
        scorePlayerTwo.text = "\(0)"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. It is true I don't actually check if the objects are Ints, great you point it out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better off pulling the integervalue straight from userdefaults

```
countWins["1"] = defaults.integerForKey("scoreOne")
countWins["2"] = defaults.integerForKey("scoreTwo")
```